# Bedeutet »Job« eigentlich, dass es sich um eine zeitlich befristete Arbeitsstelle handelt?

Tags: meaning

Ich denke, dass man bei (Arbeits-)**Stelle** im Allgemeinen explizit dazu sagt, wenn es sich um eine zeitlich **befristete** Stelle handelt.

Bei **Arbeit**, wie in

> Ich habe Arbeit.

kann man vermutlich noch nicht mal sicher sein, dass es sich um bezahlte Arbeit handelt, es kann sich dabei durchaus auch um ehrenamtliche Tätigkeiten handeln.

Wie aber sieht es mit dem Begriff **Job** aus, meint der im Allgemeinen zeitliche begrenzte Arbeiten?

Comment: Zeitlich begrenzt = befristet (z.B. ein Jahr) oder in der Arbeitszeit pro Woche beschränkt (z.B. halbtags)?

Comment: Ich denke an befristet.

Comment: Man sagt vielleicht `bei *einer* Stelle` etwas dazu - aber wieso sollte man allgemein dazu sagen ob eine Stelle befristet ist? Sehe ich nicht so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ich würde sagen: Der Begriff hat einen Bedeutungswandel hinter sich. War ein Job früher eine Nebenbeschäftigung oder eine befristete Anstellung, so ist die Bezeichnung "mein Job" heute auch für den Hauptberuf mit einem unbefristeten Vertrag gängig, analog zu der Bedeutung im Englischen. Siehe auch: Jobcenter, wo auch "richtige" Anstellungen vermittelt werden sollen.

Comment: …im Jobcenter werden eben so gut wie keine "richtigem" Anstellungen vermittelt, daher ja auch Jobcenter; ich würde den Begriff immer noch kurzfristig und auf ein bestimmtes Projekt bezogen verstehen.

Comment: Vielleicht schadet mir da meine Vertrautheit mit dem Englischen, aber für mich sind "Job" und "richtige Arbeitsstelle" Synonyme.

Answer (score 7):

Der Begriff Job ist ein wenig doppeldeutig.

Auf der einen Seite kann es ein klassisches vertragliches Arbeitsverhältnis bezeichnen, wobei es hier egal ist, ob das Ganze befristet oder unbefristet ist.

Auf der anderen Seite wird es häufig auch einfach als Alternative zum Wort "Aufgabe" verwendet ("Mein Job ist es, hier die Blumen zu pflanzen").

Comment: Das Wort egal in Nähe von befristet oder unbefristet breitet mir ein gewisses Unbehagen.

Answer (score 1):

**Arbeitsstelle** wird in der Regel für ein sozialversicherungspflichtiges Arbeitsverhältnis verwendet, unabhängig von dessen Dauer. Ob befristet oder unbefristet ergänzt wird, hängt davon ab, welches von beiden dem Sprecher besonders erwähnenswert erscheint.

**Job** kann den *Aufgabenbereich* (auch im nicht beruflichen Kontext) bezeichnen.

„Es ist mein Job, den Müll raus zu bringen.“   „Das ist mein    Traumjob.“ Hier wird zwar meist von einer Arbeitsstelle gesprochen,  aber immer der Aufgaben- und Tätigkeitsbereich gemeint. Finanzielle  und zeitliche Rahmenbedingungen können, müssen aber keine Rolle    spielen.

**Job** wird  auch für *bezahlte Arbeit* (im weitesten Sinne) verwendet. In diesem Fall ist zu unterscheiden, wie der Sprecher selbst diese Arbeit bewertet.

1. Es geht vorrangig um das Geld, die Tätigkeit selbst ist zweitrangig oder nicht zeitintensiv. Der Job wird hier als Not- oder Übergangslösung betrachtet oder aus anderen Gründen als nicht vollwertige Arbeitsstelle gesehen. Die tatsächliche Beschäftigungsdauer ist keine Grundbedingung. Beispiele:

Nebenjob, Minijob, Ferienjob
„Das ist nur ein Job für mich.“

2. Job wird als Synonym für Arbeitsstelle gebraucht. Beispiele:

„Ich habe endlich einen neuen Job!“
„Ich habe jetzt einen wirklich guten Job.“
"Hast du schon einen Job in Aussicht?"